# Building a string in Go which is "public static"?

Tags: go

I'm taking my first steps in Go. My first application shall implement a REST client. For this I'm building a `baseUrl` which all requests have in common.

```
var sb strings.Builder

sb.WriteString("http://")
sb.WriteString(host)
sb.WriteString(":")
sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(apiPortTest))
sb.WriteString("/")
sb.WriteString(basePathTest)

var baseUrl = sb.String()
```

In Java I can use a `public static` string to access this in different classes/methods.

Is there something equivalent in Go?

Comment: Just use regular function.

Comment: When using a function the string is built with each function call, right? I'd like to "build it once", then just use it.

Comment: make it exported, `BaseURL = sb.String()`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no way to do exactly that in Go, but I'd consider few alternatives:

1) Use a global variable (with obvious and known trade-offs):

```
var BaseURL = fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d/%s", host, port, path)
```

(on the other hand, since `host`, `port`, and `path` are also hard-coded, just `const BaseURL = "http://yourhost:1234/api"` would suffice).

2) Wrap that global variable in a function:

```
var baseURL = fmt.Sprintf("http://%s:%d/%s", host, port, path)

func BaseURL() string {
    return baseURL
}
```

3) (The clear winner in my opinion) pass the URL as a parameter to your client type when you use it:

```
type RESTClient struct {
    BaseURL string
    // ...
}

// on the user side:

client := &RESTClient{BaseURL: baseURL}
client.ListResources()  // or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this to achieve ***build it once***:

```
package config

// ...

var baseURL string

func BaseURL() string {

    if baseURL == "" {
        // construct the base url here

        host := "localhost"
        apiPortTest := 9090
        basePathTest := "api"

        var sb strings.Builder

        sb.WriteString("http://")
        sb.WriteString(host)
        sb.WriteString(":")
        sb.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(apiPortTest))
        sb.WriteString("/")
        sb.WriteString(basePathTest)

        baseURL = sb.String()
    }

    return baseURL
}
```

Then just call `config.BaseURL()`, the construction of the `baseURL` will happen only once on the first call.

Comment: If this might be called concurrently, it should use `sync.Once`.